# Is there any way to change the background color of the ComboBox control with DropDownList in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to change the background color of the `ComboBox` control with `DropDownStyle = DropDownList` in Windows Forms?

If I just do

```
this.comboBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

nothing changed.

I need to highlight this `ComboBox` when the user doesn't choose any item (I can't provide the default item in my case).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You also need set **DrawMode** to **OwnerDrawFixed**